# linq and remove everything before empty space if exists

Tags: c#, linq

_comboBoxItems is array

```
[0] = "01 01010304"
[1] = "01 01230304"
[2] = "01 01010784"
[3] = "01 01135404"
```

can i with linq remove everything before empty space if exist that i will get

```
[0] = "01010304"
[1] = "01230304"
[2] = "01010784"
[3] = "01135404"
```

or must i use foreach and then remove data and add it back to array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `_comboBoxItems.Select(s => s.Split(' ').Last())`, with a `.ToArray()` at the end if you require an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mycombobox.Items = mycombobox.Items.Select(x => x.Split(' ')[1]).ToArray();
```